# Why is the result of math not trivially inferred?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Given the following snippet:

```js
const a: number = 22;
```

I get the following error:

```
Type number trivially inferred from a number literal, remove type annotation.
eslint@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types
```

However it does not do that with this `c` assignment:

```js
const a = 33;
const b = 22;
const c: number = a + b;
```

Why won't the `const c` assignment throw the same warning?

Is there an ESLint rule to catch this?

Comment: From https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-inferrable-types/ it looks like only unary operations are supported.

Comment: Because the literal `22` must be a number. `valueA + valueB` is not obviously a number (if either or both `value`s is a string, for instance). It can be inferred (by looking at the types of the operands), but not, according to ESLint, "trivially".

Comment: Note that the rule says it _doesn't_ use type information, even, so it's just looking at the structure of the line. I'd guess `const a: number = 22 + 33` would be allowed too.

Comment: you are right, that is indeed allowed

Comment: No I am on a search for other eslint rules / plugins that can help me identify this.